# Laravel:Difference between Schema builder and Eloquent anyone?

Tags: database, schema, laravel, builder, eloquent

I am new to Laravel. So If I can generate tables using Schema builder and then query data using queries like `DB::table('user')->find(1)`, where does Eloquent fit in the whole scene? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eloquent is the name given to the ORM ([Object-relational mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)) that ships with Laravel. Eloquent allows you to interact with your tables as though they were objects, however Eloquent is unaware of the actual columns you have on your table.

Let's consider the simple `User` model. We want this model to query records on our `users` table.

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

}
```

That there is a *very* simple model. Now, instead of querying like this.

```
$user = DB::table('user')->find(1);
```

You can query like this.

```
$user = User::find(1);
```

Eloquent itself uses its own query builder but does fall back to the standard query builder. This means it has all the methods on the query builder available to it, and more.

The benefits here are:

1. You don't have to specify your table name on every call.
2. The code reads a whole lot better, it's syntactical sugar.
3. You can create complex relationships between tables and use eager loading.
4. You can make use of functionality such as mass assignment protection and setters/getter.
5. You get all the benefits of using a query builder as well, so you can easily switch between DBMS.

I've only touched on Eloquent. There is so much more to it. I suggest you take a look at the following resources.

- [Eloquent Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent)
- [Dayle Rees' Code Happy](http://codehappy.daylerees.com/eloquent-orm)
- [Laravel.io: Fluent and Eloquent](http://laravel.io/topic/17/what-are-fluent-and-eloquent)

Comment: You meant to say that I've to create eloquent models manually after creating the tables using Schema builder,if I want to use Eloquent?

Comment: If using Laravel 5, then the `php artisan make:model User` command will create both a migration stub for the schema builder, and a User model. Once created, you can modify both to fill in the gaps (i.e. any remaining columns, relationships etc.).